# Shortcode Function - Can't get anything else to return after running shortcode within shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

Just looking to see if anyone can help me with a problem I have when returning values within a shortcode.

```
function youtube_media_shortcode() {


return do_shortcode( '[x_video_embed no_container="true"]<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.get_field('youtubeurl', 'option').'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>[/x_video_embed]' );
return '<div class="youtube-text">'.get_field('youtubetext', 'option').'</div>';

}
```

The first part of this returns fine with the video but then it does not seem to return the next line. If I remove the first line then the second one returns fine. I presume it has something to do with the do_shortcode but I have no idea what!

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't call return twice in a function, as it isn't supported and only the first return is evaluated.

What you can do is assign the first do_shortcode to a variable and return the variable concatenanted to the second return.

```
function youtube_media_shortcode() {

    $shortcode_output = do_shortcode( '[x_video_embed no_container="true"]<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.get_field('youtubeurl', 'option').'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>[/x_video_embed]' );

    return $shortcode_output . '<div class="youtube-text">'.get_field('youtubetext', 'option').'</div>';

}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, that makes sense. I've tested your code as working so thank you very much!